# search form with multiple select fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have made search form, where are list menus. it works very well if I fill every field of the form but, I want that all the fields  work independently, like if you fill only one field it must show the result which is about this field only, and if you choos another field it must give seemlier result. my code looks like this. thank you beforehand.

```
 <?php 
 mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
 $mxare = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mxare']);
 $raioni = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['raioni']);
 $type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']);
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dzeglebi WHERE mxare = '$mxare' AND   
 raioni ='$raioni' AND  type = '$type' ORDER BY title ASC", $db); 
 $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @njk Do you have that ready for copypasting? ...

Comment: @Cobra_Fast It's available on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/3881905). Not sure who put it together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this;

```
$where = array("1=1");
if (!empty($_POST["field_1"])) {
    $where[] = sprintf("field_1='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["field_1"]));
}
// if (!empty($_POST["field_2"])) {
// and so on...

// convert where to string with AND or OR
$where = join(" AND ", $where);
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dzeglebi WHERE $where");
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your data, you can try like following

```
$mxare = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mxare']);
$raioni = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['raioni']);
$type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']);

// here 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dzeglebi WHERE 1==1 " ;
if ( isset($mxare)) $sql = $sql . " AND " . " mxare = '$mxare'";
if ( isset($raioni)) $sql = $sql . " AND " . " raioni= '$raioni'";
.....
.....

$result = mysql_query($sql)
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: I wrote the code as you wrote but it doesn't work, my code is like this:
<? mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
 $mxare = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mxare']);
 $raioni = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['raioni']);
 $type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']);
 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dzeglebi WHERE 1==1 " ;
if ( isset($mxare)) $sql = $sql . " AND " . " mxare = '$mxare'";
if ( isset($raioni)) $sql = $sql . " AND " . " raioni= '$raioni'";
if ( isset($type)) $sql = $sql . " AND " . " type = '$type'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo '$title'; ?>

Comment: right now i haven't test environment. you could try `if ( isset($_POST['raioni'])....` like this. but i hope you got mechanism, depending on your `if` condition you need to extend the query.